# Is Following Set Close Under Operation

Tags: group-theory

> Let $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{-1\},*)$ s.t $a*b=a+b+ab$ Is the operation closed?

So we are looking whereas the following is possible $a+b+ab=-1$ the only correlation I found was to Vieta's formula but it does not seems to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $ab+a+b+1 = (a+1)(b+1)=0$

Comment: Why can we freely add $-1$ from both sides? does $a*b=a+b+ab$ define a single operation on the set?

Comment: Yes, but maybe we are limited to the operation $a*b=a+b+ab$ meaning that if $ab+a+b=-1$ we can just use the operation $a*b=a+b+ab$ let say we want to add arbitrary $c$ from the left it will be $c*(ab+a+b)=c*(-1)$

Comment: Why  should we use only $*$ if it self is defined by standard $+$ and $\cdot$.

Comment: I do not know, that is why I am asking :)

Answer (score 1):

While John Watson's answer is certainly the most elegant, you can also do it more... brute forcefully.

Assume that $a*b=-1$ and $a,b\neq -1$. Then, $a+b+ab=-1$ can be rewritten to $$a(1+b)=-1-b$$

and further to $$a(1+b)=-(1+b)$$

which should lead you to a contradiction.

Comment: Why we need to assume that $a*b=-1$? let assume $a,b\neq -1$ then $a+b+ab=-1\iff a(1+b)=-1(b+1)\iff a=-1$

Comment: @gbox Sure, that works too.